# Moving Django-Paypal to production

Tags: python-3.4, django-1.8, django-paypal

I have tested my Django application with Django-Paypal. I followed [this](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html) tutorial. Everything works good as expected.

Now when I take the application to production. I did two things in setttings.py

1. Removed 'PAYPAL_TEST=True'
2. Updated 'PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL' with real Paypal Account email ID.

But when I click pay button, I am redirected to sandbox.paypal.com instead of paypal.com production server.

What am I missing here?

I am using Python 3.4 / Django 1.8.6 / Django-Paypal 0.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing 'PAYPAL_TEST=True' I made it 'PAYPAL_TEST=False'. Simple!

Comment: It is not working. It is saying We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different payment method. Any idea what is the issue.